# PVP Power / Resilence for Hunter

Tags: world-of-warcraft

First of all, sorry about my English. 
I'm new at PVP and I need help about PVP stats. Which stat is better for a Hunter; PVP Power or Resilience ? Noxxic says PVP Power is better but Askmrrobot is suggesting me Resilience gems. What should I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need to realize is as far as PvP purposes go, you need to decide one of two things.

First off is what is your play style?

-Are you a stand in one spot and dps or kite the enemy and keep on your toes player?
-Do you prefer to be able to kill the enemy as fast as possible, or sit back and do a steady amount of damage but have a much higher survival chance?

Each option provides it benefits, and this is true for the stats as well, PvP Power increases the amount of your damage that will break through the enemies Resilience.  Given all players start off with 40% Resilience now naturally, PvP Power will give you the highest survivability in the short term as you should be able to outdamage another player.

In the long term you need both, one will reduce the amount of damage you take and the other will increase the amount of damage you do. Again, stat prioritization is greatly dependent on you and how you want to be able to dish out and receive damage in PvP.

Simply put, if you want to take less damage, get Resilience. If you want to do more damage, get PvP Power.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the amount of burst that your opponents can pull off, there has been a shift from PvP Power to PvP Resilience across most high-rated players (but not all of them).

Unless you can comfortably prevent most of the damage from all strong attacks (eg. Chaos Bolt, Frostbomb, Stampede) or burst windows (eg. Avenging Wrath, Berserker Rage, Shadow Dance), I would recommend prioritizing PvP Resilience over PvP Power. However, if you are confident that you can deal enough damage that you would severely limit your opponent's ability to use their burst against you or that you can effectively counter them with your CDs (eg. It's fairly easy to prevent Mages from damaging you, but more difficult to prevent Warlocks) then I would recommend pushing for PvP Power.

Personally, I've found the difference between choosing PvP Resilience over PvP Power to be similar to the difference of doing 2v2 Arena with a healer and a DPS or double DPS. Using two DPS instead of a healer will make all of your wins faster, but it will make your losses faster as well. Choosing PvP Power over PvP Resilience will have a similar effect.